# how to get the latest data from relationship table for each record in original table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm working on a project using Laravel 10.

My goal is to show all `customers` data and added with a field containing the date of the last `penawaran` data made by that customer. Each Customer can create multiple Penawaran, but each Penawaran always have only one Customer.

The problem I'm encountering is when `$row->updated_at` variable is printed out in the views, it shows the `updated_at` of the `customers` record instead.

what am I doing wrong? any help is appreciated.

this is my code:

`migrations/..create_penawarans_table`:

```
$table->id();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('customer_id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
$table->timestamps();
```

`migrations/..create_customers_table`:

```
$table->id();
$table->string('nama');
$table->string('alamat');
$table->string('telepon');
$table->string('email')->nullable();
$table->string('slug')->unique();
$table->timestamps();
```

`models/Customer.php`:

```
    public function penawaran()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Penawaran::class);
    }
```

`models/Penawaran.php`:

```
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Customer::class, 'customer_id');
    }
```

`PenawaranController.php`:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = Customer::orderBy('nama', 'ASC')
        ->with(['penawaran' => function ($query) {
            $query->whereNotNull('updated_at');
            $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
        }]);

    $view_data = [
        'page_title' => 'List Customer',
        'active' => 'customer',
        'data' => $data->get(),
    ];

    return view('customer.index', $view_data);
}
```

`views/customer/index.blade.php`:

```
//
    @foreach ($data as $row)
        <tr>
            <td class="px-2 fit">{{ $loop->index + 1 }}.</td>
            <td>{{ $row->nama }}</td>
            <td class="fit">{{ $row->telepon }}</td>
            <td class="fit">{{ date('d F Y H:i:s', strtotime($row->updated_at)); }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
//
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay so first of all if the Customer has many Penawaran then you can not do belongs to in the Customer model, you will have hasMany in the Customer and belongs to Customer in the Penawaran model.

In the Customer Model,

```
public function penawarans() {
    return $this->hasMany(Penawaran::class, 'customer_id');
}
```

The above relationship will give the collection of many penawarans records that will belongs to the particular customer but if you want the latest record then define another relationship hasOne,

```
public function latestPenawaran() {
    return $this->hasOne(Penawaran::class, 'customer_id')->latest('updated_at');
}
```

In the Penawaran Model,

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customer_id');
}
```

Then in the method index,

```
public function index()
{
    $data = Customer::orderBy('nama', 'ASC')
        ->with(['latestPenawaran' => function ($query) {
            $query->whereNotNull('updated_at');
        }]);

    $view_data = [
        'page_title' => 'List Customer',
        'active' => 'customer',
        'data' => $data->get(),
    ];

    return view('customer.index', $view_data);
}
```

And then the blade,

```
@foreach ($data as $row)
    <tr>
        <td class="px-2 fit">{{ $loop->index + 1 }}.</td>
        <td>{{ $row->nama }}</td>
        <td class="fit">{{ $row->telepon }}</td>
        <td class="fit">{{ date('d F Y H:i:s', strtotime($row->latestPenawaran->updated_at)); }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```